# Does this seem like a ruby Time equality bug?

Tags: ruby, time, equality

Why the `false` in the 2nd comparison? I am not loading any libraries.

```
puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION
t = Time.now
t1 = Time.at(t.to_f)
t2 = Time.at(t.to_f)
puts( t1 == t2 )
puts( t == t1 )
puts( t.to_f == t1.to_f )
printf "%.64f\n%.64f\n%.64f\n", t, t1, t2
```

Output:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
true
false
true
1347661545.4348440170288085937500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1347661545.4348440170288085937500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1347661545.4348440170288085937500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I get all `true`s on 1.8.7. What's going on?

I updated the script to show that the floats are the same, as far as I can tell. Am I missing something?

Comment: This doesn't explain it working on 1.8.7 but remember that `to_f` loses precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs on Time.to_f: "Note that IEEE 754 double is not accurate enough to represent number of nanoseconds from the Epoch." To illustrate @oldrinb's comment:

```
puts RUBY_DESCRIPTION # ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
t = Time.now
p t.subsec #=> (40189433/100000000); # a Rational, note the last digits 33
p t.to_f   #=> 1347661635.4018943   # last digit missing 3
```

[Time#subsec documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-subsec): "The lowest digit of #to_f and subsec is different because IEEE 754 double is not accurate enough to represent the rational. The accurate value is returned by subsec."

Comment: Thanks for the info. Never knew about `subsec`.

Comment: @Kelvin: neither did I before your question :). But the method did not exist in 1.8.7, so storing the nanoseconds as a Rational is probably a 1.9 refinement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet that this is a classic float precision issue. Specifically, when you call `#to_f`, you are likely losing precision present in the original object.

You can see this easily if you compare the `#nsec` values of each object:

```
1.9.3p194 :059 > t = Time.now
 => 2012-09-14 15:29:59 -0700
1.9.3p194 :060 > t2 = Time.at(t.to_f)
 => 2012-09-14 15:29:59 -0700
1.9.3p194 :062 > t.nsec
 => 489932427
1.9.3p194 :063 > t2.nsec
 => 489932537
```

The reason that `Time.at(t.to_f) == Time.at(t.to_f)` likely succeeds is that both have the same float precision loss in their input, so their inputs are indeed identical.

So, in summary, it's buggy behavior, but it's not a bug /per se/, because it's tied to a fundamental caveat of float arithmetic.

Comment: It's kind of a tie between you and steenslag in terms of helpfulness. Nice info on `nsec`. It's a new 1.9 feature I see.